# How to call presentViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet, presentmodalviewcontroller

Here is the situation: I have a class MainView (which is a UIViewController) and call from it an UIActionSheetDelegate class. I want to use the method presentViewController, but the following code does not work (currently being called in the ActionSheet class):

```
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

I am a little confused regarding where I should call the method from (MainView or the ActionSheetDelegate).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call the method *on* the UIViewController that is your MainView, and *pass* it your UIViewController you want to be the ActionSheet.

```
[mainViewController presentViewController:actionSheetController animated:YES];
```

To dismiss the UIActionSheet, `dimissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` is a method for the UIActionSheet that you can implement. The method can be called by whoever (so if you want to dismiss it from your mainview have a reference to the action sheet and do something like `[self.myActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`

The method is also called whenever the 'cancel' button is clicked by the user.

Comment: Great. Then how do I dismiss the ActionSheetController from the view.

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES] does not work